# SQL Server culture info

Tags: sql-server

My application work with SQL Server and it works with different servers with different culture infos (for example Ru-Ru, En-US, etc.) ... How can I insert data value to it? I need to convert my DateTime to string depends on server's culture, but how?

Comment: Use 'YYYYMMDD' format or 'YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS' for datetime. It doesn't depend on server culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `culture Specific conversion` you can use:

```
String s = "14.12.2011";

d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("Ru-Ru")); //Russia
d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")); //English United States
```

But if you really can't decide what culture to use when converting dates to strings and vice-versa, and the dates are never meant to be shown to a user, then you can use the `Invariant Culture`:

```
String s = "14/12/2011" //invariant culture formatted date

d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //parse invariant culture date

s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //convert to invariant culture string
```

And if you are converting your dates and saving them as strings you can use `ISO-8601 date format` i.e `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS`, this will always work, regardless of currently selected language or culture settings in SQL Server.

The following `Stackoverflow` question may help you:

Reference: [DateTime issue when global culture of the server is different on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874869/datetime-issue-when-global-culture-of-the-server-is-different-on-different-serve)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to use InvariantCulture and post result here tomorrow

Comment: Yep! It seems like it helps :) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this problem happens again... "InvariantCulture" doesn't help :(