# ASP.NET Core MVC DateTime parameter not parsing ISO date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC have methods that receive as parameters in the body dates, and once I publish to `Azure` it will always try to parse it as `mm/dd/yyyy`.
The app is intended to run in one country, with only one timezone and no daylight saving time policy in place. But I'd like to do this the right way. I read some solutions 
Doing research, I found all the issues `datetime` represents in programming, read and listened to Jon Skeet and Johnson about the same topic. Found `moment.js` and `Noda Time`. 
Also found out many suggestions about adding custom parsers to solve this. I don't think that would be acceptable. Even accepting that it is not the default way of parsing, shouldn't there be a configuration so I can make the framework parse with the standard?
So my questions are:

- Why is the framework not parsing the datetime using ISO 8601?
- What is the correct approach to do this?

Comment: This has been asked quite frequently. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874869/datetime-issue-when-global-culture-of-the-server-is-different-on-different-serve/7875204#7875204. Or you could change the default culture like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497903/cannot-set-default-and-only-culture-in-asp-net-core-app

Comment: @jcemoller thanks for the comment. I hadn't seen those links before, although as I state in my question I've seen similar. I ended up changing the culture for the moment, but my question is if there isn't a way to make MVC work with the standard by default, not how to parse a date string. Thanks!